# Create MSK Connector from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I'm trying to create an MSK Connector from a Lambda function. Code right now is something as simple as this:

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('kafkaconnect')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = client.create_connector(
        # Connector configs here
    )
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.loads(json.dumps(response, default=str))
    }
```

The problem, from what I can tell, is that the `create_connector` method will only finish when the connector is created. This will fail because the creation time exceeds Lambda's 15 min timeout.

Is there any other way to simply trigger the creation of the connector and not wait for it to finish the execution?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any value in doing something in Lambda that exceeds Lambda's max runtime? Why does the connector take 15+ minutes? Is this not an async API?

Comment: @jarmod What I failed to understand was why the creation was taking more than 15 min, because I also thought this was an async API. And it is - The problem was in the configuration. I had the configuration wrong and for some reason instead of failing, I guess the create_connector method entered in a state where it wouldn't terminate. I'll try to figure out why this was happening